# Which should I use? Project::select("*") or new Project()

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I don't know the difference between the two, but which should I use?
Which is better when bringing data from DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new Project()` is used when inserting to the table. Example:

```
$project = new Project();
$project->name = "Sample Name";
$project->save();
```

`Project::select("*")` is getting data. Example:

```
Project::select("*")->get();
```

You may study the Laravel documentation here: https://laravel.com

Eloquent Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent

There are also free tutorial videos here at Laracasts: https://laracasts.com/